# Getting BeanCreationException when I try to run spring boot web application?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I created a web project in intelliJ. then I created Application.kt and HomeController.kt . Now I am trying to run this web application using **./gradlew :bootRun** , But it's throwing following exception .
I don't know , what am I doing wrong? can anyone figure it out? what is the actual problem here .
Thanks in Advance

**stack trace**

```
2018-03-07 17:57:53.868  INFO 26063 --- [           main] ApplicationKt                            : Starting ApplicationKt on xyz-x541uj with PID 26063 (/home/xyz/Desktop/root/intelliJ/WebPro/build/classes/kotlin/main started by xyz in /home/xyz/Desktop/root/intelliJ/WebPro)
2018-03-07 17:57:53.878  INFO 26063 --- [           main] ApplicationKt                            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-07 17:57:53.971  INFO 26063 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@667a738: startup date [Wed Mar 07 17:57:53 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-07 17:57:54.123  WARN 26063 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2018-03-07 17:57:55.405  INFO 26063 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-03-07 17:57:55.431  INFO 26063 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-03-07 17:57:55.432  INFO 26063 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2018-03-07 17:57:55.442  INFO 26063 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-03-07 17:57:55.525  INFO 26063 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-03-07 17:57:55.525  INFO 26063 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1557 ms
2018-03-07 17:57:55.676  INFO 26063 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-03-07 17:57:55.680  INFO 26063 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-07 17:57:55.681  INFO 26063 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-07 17:57:55.681  INFO 26063 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-07 17:57:55.681  INFO 26063 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-07 17:57:55.722  WARN 26063 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [/home/ankush/Desktop/root/intelliJ/WebPro/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/webpro/controller/HomeController.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
2018-03-07 17:57:55.724  INFO 26063 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-03-07 17:57:55.737  INFO 26063 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-07 17:57:55.743 ERROR 26063 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [/home/ankush/Desktop/root/intelliJ/WebPro/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/webpro/controller/HomeController.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:18) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils$KotlinDelegate.findPrimaryConstructor(BeanUtils.java:727) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.findPrimaryConstructor(BeanUtils.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        ... 21 common frames omitted



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

**build.gradle**

```
       buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE")

    }
}

        group 'com.xxx.web'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

**Application.kt**

```
       import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan



@ComponentScan("com.webpro")
@SpringBootApplication
open class Application

fun main(args:Array<String>)
{
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java,*args)
}
```

**HomeController.kt**

```
    package com.webpro.controller

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController



@RestController
class HomeController
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    fun greeting() : String
    {
        return "Hello World !"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something in the code is trying to use Kotlin [reflection](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html). In order to cut down the size of the runtime library, Kotlin reflection features are provided separately from the standard library, as a separate JAR.

To add this dependency to your build, update your `build.gradle` file by putting this line inside the `dependencies` block:

`compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"`